# How can I correctly use the method "apply()" in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I'm trying to create a new column and classify the institutions with the conditions in the code below. But I keep receving the error message 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

```
def rank_level(group):
    if (group["world_rank"] < 101).bool():
        group["rank_level"] = "First Tier"
    elif (100 < group["world_rank"] < 201).bool():
        group["rank_level"] = "Second Tier"
    elif (200 < group['world_rank'] < 301).bool():
        group["rank_level"] = "Third Tier"
    else:
        group["rank_level"] = "Other Tiers"
        
    return group

df = pd.read_csv('datasets/cwurData.csv')
df = df.groupby('country').apply(rank_level)
df
```

I read other similar problems here in stack overflow about the importance to use .bool() when using if/while but I couldn't make it right. What's wrong with the code?

The data that i'm using is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_gASLy4umxfxlDunz_6UvQtY0MapqJ1N?usp=sharing

Comment: you don't use `.apply` in this situation. use `numpy.where`, `pandas.cut`

Comment: provide reproducible sample data and show your desired output

Answer (score 0):

First, access is denied. Better off making it public for a while.
Second, this is tricky and I too usually make the same mistake, although I do no use bool anywhere.[image]

Since I do not have access to your data, I ran into some random data I had.

I am basically trying to create a new column (*'place'*) by using the *"region"* column by creating a user defined function "*find_place*"

The function takes in region value i.e pass your condition column - and then runs your condition. Then return the value that you want to target column to have.

However, understand that .apply runs row-wise.

So, if I had to modify your code, I would use the following:

```
def calc_tier(rank):
    if rank < 100:
        return "First Tier"
    elif rank > 100 & rank <= 200:
        return "Second Tier"
    elif rank > 200 & rank <= 201:
        return "Thired Tier"
```

Just tweak the code to suit your purpose.